# Homebrew installed bash-completion not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

I have installed [bash-completion via homebrew](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) and added the code below to `.bash_profile`

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Bash completion does not work, even though there are many valid bash-completion scripts in `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d`

```
$ ls /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
abook               mc
adb-completion.bash     mcrypt
ant             mdadm
apache2ctl          medusa
apt             minicom
apt-build           mkinitrd
aptitude            module-init-tools
```

When executing bash-completion manually in a bash prompt, I get the error

```
$ [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
-bash: .: /Users/hanxue/.bash_completion: is a directory
$ source /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
-bash: .: /Users/hanxue/.bash_completion: is a directory
```

Comment: Simply run `brew install bash-completion` then edit your bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I have a `~/.bash_completion` **directory**, when the bash-completion script is expecting a **file**.

Deleting the directory solved the problem, and bash-completion is now working

```
$ ls -ld ~/.bash_completion/
drwxr-xr-x  3 hanxue  staff  102 Oct  1  2013 /Users/hanxue/.bash_completion/
$ rm -R ~/.bash_completion
$ [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
```

Looking at the [bash-completion source code](http://git.debian.org/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git), I found this line

```
# source user completion file
[[ $BASH_COMPLETION != ~/.bash_completion && -r ~/.bash_completion ]] \
    && . ~/.bash_completion
```

Comment: if you want a directory to install individual completion files, use `~/.local/share/bash-completion`, as described in the [official FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md#faq)